# A good name for a URL path and query string and fragment?

Tags: http, url, web, networking

URLs can be broken up into these components:

Sample URL: http://www.server.com:8080/path?query=string#fragment

- protocol = http
- host = www.server.com
- port = 8080
- path = /path
- query = ?query=string
- fragment = #fragment

Is there an established name for everything that comes after port (path, query, and fragment)? I was tempted to just call this "path" but that is not a good name as it does not include the query and fragment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [IETF URI Spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2) defines the combination of these elements (path, query, and fragment) as a **Relative Reference**.

Comment: Within that, there are more specific terms as well: 
"A relative reference that begins with a single slash character is termed an *absolute-path reference*.  A relative reference that does not begin with a slash character is termed a *relative-path reference*."

Comment: This is not correct. The ABNF in the spec you linked to defines `relative-ref  = relative-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]`, where `relative-part = "//" authority path-abempty / [...] `. In other words: `relative-ref` can also start with `// authority`, where authority is optional userinfo, followed by mandatory host and an optional port.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps "relative URL", as in "relative to Site Root"

Answer (score -1):

there is no established name for everything together due to them all being different. Also you forgot the parameters part of the url.  The parameters go in the query.

Answer (score -1):

The URL structure you are giving is containing the basic elements, and the fragment is usually coming before the query, the query in general is used when you are listing a part of data, so you need to access to it by this query, and parameters if needed.
Here a good [review](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/creatingUrls.html) to list the steps for creating a good url.

Comment: The query parameters come first and the fragments comes at the end.

Comment: The query parameters come BEFORE the fragment.